# ¿Cómo multiplico dos listas que almacenaron información de la entrada estándar?

Tags: python

Estoy por terminar un proyecto que he estado realizando desde hace unas semanas atrás.
He estado intentando multiplicar dos listas que recibieron datos de la entrada estándar, pero no logro entender la razón por la cuál al multiplicar las dos listas me multiplica la cantidad de elementos que existe en la "lista a" por el mismo elemento que existe en la "lista b", algo así: `a=[2, 3, 4]` y `b = [12, 13, 25]` al realizar print me arroja esto: `12.0012.00, 13.0013.0013.00, 25.0025.0025.0025.00`

Utilizo la función zip para iterarlos y multiplicarlos (incluso he intentado con numpy y lamda, pero sigo con el mismo problema).

```
for (x,y) in zip(result, almacenado):
    mult=x*y
    print(mult)
```

Aquí está el código completo:

```
dic=['Columnas', 'Trabes', 'Losas']
numeros = {'Columnas': 0, 'Trabes': 0, 'Losas': 0}
almacenado=[] #---------------------> Aquí está la primera lista
result=[] #------------------------> Aquí está la segunda lista
for datos in numeros:
    numeros[datos] = int(input(f'¿Cuántas {datos} tiene en total su estructura? : '))
    almacenado.append(numeros[datos])

for dato, valor in numeros.items():
     print(f'Su estructura tiene {valor} {dato}')
print('\n\n')

dimensiones = {'Columna': [], 'Trabe': [], 'Losa': []}
datos = ['altura', 'longitud', 'profundidad']
result=[]

for tipo in dimensiones:
    for dato in datos:
        dimensiones[tipo].append(float(input(f'Ingrese la {dato} de su {tipo}: ')))
   
    def multiply(numbers):  
        total = 1
        for i in numbers:
            total *= i  
        return total  

    print(f'El volúmen de su {tipo} es de', "{0:.2f}".format(multiply((dimensiones[tipo]))) + 'cm^3\n')
    result.append("{0:.2f}".format(multiply((dimensiones[tipo]))))
print(*result, sep=', ')

for (x,y) in zip(result, almacenado):
    mult=x*y
    print(mult)
```

¿A qué se debe este error y qué puedo implementar para solucionarlo? De antemano muchísimas gracias por todo el apoyo que me han dado hasta ahora, saludos!

Comment: No se entiende. Agrega un ejemplo con listas de entrada, la salida correcta y la salida actual para poder comparar.

Comment: Estás metiendo en la lista `result` cadenas, en vez de floats. (debido a que usas una cadena de formato para ello)

Comment: Se me ocurre iterar elemento por elemento y copiarlo a una nueva lista, pero no sé si sea óptimo, en todo caso, ¿cómo puedo corregirlo?

Comment: Cambia la forma en que metes los datos a la lista, para no usar cadenas de formato. Por ejemplo `result.append(multiply(dimensiones[tipo]))`

Comment: El problema viene de que la operación `"2.5"*2` no es lo mismo que `2.5*2`. En el segundo caso multiplicas dos números y el resultado es `5.0` como cabe esperar. En el primer caso estás multiplicando una cadena por un número, y el resultado es `"2.52.5"`, por la misma razón que `"foo"*2` da como resultado `"foofoo"`. Tú estabas metiendo cadenas en vez de números en tu lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya te ha dicho abulafia, tu error se debe a que `result.append("{0:.2f}".format(multiply((dimensiones[tipo]))))` lo que está haciendo es meter una cadena de texto en la lista `result`.

Viendo los comentarios, dices:

> puedo concluir que las cadenas de formato alteran la forma de la lista

No es que alteren la lista, es que la has creado directamente con cadenas de texto, lo que pasa es que has formateado a cadena lo que querías meter en la lista.

Si tienes un numero:

```
numero = 5
print(type(numero))  # Devuelve <class 'int'>
```

Y formateas una cadena, esa cadena es lo que es un string:

```
texto = f'{numero}'
print(type(texto))  # Devuelve <class 'str'>
```

Pero si vuelves a hacer:

```
print(type(numero))  # Devuelve <class 'int'>
```

No se ha modificado la variable `numero`.

Por eso al cambiar a `result.append(multiply(dimensiones[tipo]))` te ha funcionado, ya que estás metiendo directamente numeros en la lista, y no texto.

**Posible mejora**

Dicho esto, puedes acortar un poco el código si quieres, almacenando todo en `datos`.

```
datos = {'Columna': {}, 'Trabe': {}, 'Losa': {}}
dimensiones = ['altura', 'longitud', 'profundidad']

for elemento in datos:
    multip = 1
    cantidad = int(input(f'¿Cuántas {elemento}s tiene en total su estructura? : '))
    for dimension in dimensiones:
        multip *= float(input(f'Ingrese la {dimension} de su {elemento}: '))
    datos[elemento][cantidad] = multip
    print(f'Su estructura tiene {cantidad} {elemento}s con un volumen individual de: {multip:.2f} y un volumen total de: {cantidad * multip:.2f}')
```

Esto te genera un diccionario de este estilo, para 1 columna de 1x2x3, 2 Trabes de 4x5x6 y 3 Losas de 7x8x9:

```
print(datos)
# Devuelve {'Columna': {1: 6.0}, 'Trabe': {2: 120.0}, 'Losa': {3: 504.0}}
```

Donde la clave es la cantidad y el valor la multiplicación de las dimensiones (también se podría guardar cada dimensión individual, pero no lo utilizas más en tu código.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la explicación y por sacarme de la duda, me han ayudado bastante. Voy a practicar más las listas para almacenar datos y así evitar este tipo de errores. Muchas gracias también por explicarme aún más a detalle cómo puedo reducir mi código aún más. Saludos!

Comment: Lo único que me genera dudas es que tal y como tienes el código, aunque metas varias columnas, estas siempre van a tener las mismas dimensiones. Lo mismo pasa con trabes y losas.

Comment: En ICIV (ingeniería civil) hay diferentes formas de armar la estructura, en este caso son de hormigón. La distribución de materiales se realiza con una regla 1:2:3. Primeramente se utilizan unas cantidades por defecto que no aparecen en el código pero que son tomadas en cuenta. Después se multiplica cada elemento por el volumen de las columnas, trabes y losas. Estos resultados se suman y se obtiene un peso individual de cada componente estructural. Con la cantidad total de elementos estructurales, se multiplica con el peso individual y se obtiene lo que estoy buscando

Comment: Hay otros factores que también son tomados en cuenta como la densidad de los materiales pero eso se obtiene mediante integrales, específicamente una integral triple

Comment: Si, sé de lo que me hablas (soy ingeniero de obras públicas). Lo decía únicamente porque en la estructura las columnas, trabes y losas no tienen porqué ser todas iguales (aunque generalmente lo sean si la estructura es "sencilla").

Comment: Sí, en este caso todas las columnas tienen las mismas dimensiones porque la estructura es sencilla (una casa con las mismas dimensiones), estoy enterado que las dimensiones de estos componentes varía mucho en distintas edificaciones.